# Cyclic Galois extension $F$ with $[F:\mathbb{Q}]=6$ implies $F$ is not a splitting field of a poly of degree $3$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Let $F$ be a cyclic Galois extension of $\mathbb{Q}$, the field of rational numbers, such that $[F : \mathbb{Q}] = 6$. Show that $F$ is not a splitting field of a polynomial of degree $3$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

---

Here is my trial:

For me, the starting point here is Cyclic Galois extension, so $\operatorname{Gal}(F/\mathbb{Q}) \simeq \mathbb{Z}_6$ (Since $[F:\mathbb{Q}]=6$ and it is Cyclic)

Now I want to show that $F$ is not a splitting field of $f(x) = x^3+ ax^2+bx+c \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ and I stuck with this issue.

Is my approach correct? Or are there another simple approach?

Comment: Have you covered the fact that the Galois group can be realized as a group of permutation of the roots of $f(x)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that $F$ was a splitting field of a degree 3 - polynomial. As the degree 3 - polynomial is irreducible and separable, its Galois-Group can only be a transitive subgroup of $S_3$. But $\mathbb{Z}_6$ is not a subgroup of $S_3$.

Answer (score 6):

Let $f$ be a cubic, irreducible over the rationals. Let it have zeros $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ in a splitting field $F$. Let $K={\bf Q}(\alpha)$, so $[K:{\bf Q}]=3$. If $\beta$ is in $K$, then $K$ is a splitting field for $f$, and we're done. So assume $\beta$ is not in $K$. Then $F$ has (at least) two distinct subfields of index two, namely $K$ and ${\bf Q}(\beta)$. But the cyclic group of order six does not have two subgroups of order two, and we're done.

Comment: Sometimes seeing a simple argument makes my day.